# Determining the "dominant" color in an image

Tags: distributions, measurement

I'm attempting to make a simple mosaic generator, where it takes a photo, then uses hundreds of other photos to represent each pixel. To do so, I want to determine the dominant color of each picture I am using as a tile, so I can know what colors it can represent. I have an array containing the RGB values of each pixel in the image, so it is not hard for me to manipulate the data. The issue is that the images I will be using are completely random, so I have no prior knowledge of the distributions of colors (meaning that simply using mean/mode etc would be very inaccurate). I am thinking some sort of specialized mode, since it might capture concentrated colors well, but I am not too sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing to think about is whether RGB is the appropriate form for your data. You may find the [CIELUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV), or some other color space more useful for your task.

You could classify each tile as [$R_s$, $G_s$, $B_s$], where $R_s = \sum R_{xy}$, the sum of all the R values in the tile image. (Or use LUV, or whatever color space you choose.) You have then placed each tile in a 3D space and could use Nearest Neighbor methods to find which tiles most closely match the RGB (LUV) value for a pixel in your image.

Actually, the answer depends on what you mean by, "The issue is that the images I will be using are completely random". Do you mean the images for tiles, or the images you will be mosaic'ing? Do you not have access to all of your tile images at once (i.e. to build the [R, G, B] space for them)?